# Вставка пробельного символа после различных цифр Python

Tags: python, строки, pandas, re

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть таблица, в которой указаны различные названия лекарств с указанием веса, например: Аспирин 250мг,Кеторол 100мг. Необходимо отделить цифры от единиц измерения пробелом.

Пытался решить проблему через `re.sub` вроде этого:

```
df.name.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\dмг', ' мг', x))
df.name.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'мг', ' мг', x))
```

, но в таком случае, в первом примере я заменяю последнюю цифру пробелом, а в следующем - заменяю все места с мг на *пробел*мг, а в названиях лекарств эти буквы также могут встречаться, так что тоже не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать квантификаторы. И вообще, обойтись без re.sub:

```
df.name.str.replace(r"(\d+)(мг)", r"\1 \2", regex = True)
```